# How to access global variables during multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, global

I have written the following toy-code using multiprocessing in Python.

I want the function `func` to run in parallel and also write to the global variables: `var`, `varr` and `varrr`.
The following code however only prints zeros for `var`, `varr` and `varrr`.

How do I make `func` modify the global variables `var`, `varr` and `varrr`???

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools
import numpy as np

p = 3
ind = range(p)
ind_list = list(itertools.product(ind,ind,ind))

var = np.zeros([p,p,p])
varr = np.zeros([p,p,p])
varrr = np.zeros([p,p,p])

def func(ind_list):
    global var, varr, varrr
    i = ind_list[0]
    j = ind_list[1]
    k = ind_list[2]
    var[i][j] = i + j + k
    varr[i][j] = i*j*k
    varrr[i][j] = 2*i*j*k

for a in range(p):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.map(func,ind_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('\n\n',var,'\n\n',varr,'\n\n',varrr,'\n\n')
```

Comment: processes have independent memory space. They do not share global variables. Other methods exist to share data between processes.

Comment: @Mathieu Please help me modify the code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments already mentioned, multiprocessing does not share memory (i.e. you can't access global variables from within the processes).
You can use pipes to share information for between processes.

Another option is to use Threading (which shares memory).
However, this will technically not run completely in parallel due to the Global Interpreter lock.